# FromName --> ReplyTo Name wordpress multisite contact form

Tags: multisite, phpmailer

When the form email lands in my inbox, I would like the "from email" (FromName) to reflect the senders email address name. This is with the popular recaptcha form plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/recaptcha-form/

Instead, the email comes in with the mother-site-tld.com domain - the name of the multisite not even the subsite - in the fromname field, which makes it a pain to reply to.

Yet this works fine and dandy on other multisites I have and I cannot recall going to any great lengths to get it to work correctly ever before ...

Thanks

Phillip

Answer (score 0):

By default wordpress uses `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` variable to get your current hostname.

You have two filters available in wordpress to change from name / email:

`add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'username@example.org');`
`add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'username');`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
/*
* Plugin Name: Just Use the Blog Name
* Description: Ensures that the FromName is the BlogName
* Plugin URI:  
* Version:     0.1
* Author:      Bottomofthestack
* Author URI:  
* License:     MIT
*/
function just_use_the_blog_name(){
 return get_option('blogname'); 
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'just_use_the_blog_name' );
```

Still leaves the problem that the replyto probably ought to simply be the email of the sender, not my blogname, but that is probably a question for the recaptcha plugin author?

NB this doesn't work in mu-plugins, which would be handy

Thanks